# References Non-Public Selectors in iOS App

Tags: ios, application-loader, xtify

I submitted an app update and it successfully uploaded, but gave validation warnings of:

> The app references non-public selectors in Payload/path.app/App:read,
>   setCountry:, setTimeStamp:, timeStamp, updateMessage:

I have never seen this before, and I have added nothing to the app from the last time it was submitted.  I use Xtify for Push Notifications, but have put in the latest version that doesn't use the UDID that prior SDKs had used.  Any thoughts where this may be coming from?

UPDATE:

The code comes from the Xtify library, specifically found in the Xlhmsupport.h file.  What is weird is that I didn't get this message just last Wednesday when submitted a different app with the same Xtify library in it.  Did Apple change something?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has in it's private API methods with the same names. So static code analyzer warns about it. I had the same issue with `base64Encoding` two years ago. But Apple approved my app.

Comment: Just odd because submitted different app with same library less than a week ago and didn't get the validation warnings.

Comment: I don't know the reason of this odd behavior. Just sharing my experience.